# Integrating arcGIS map into Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, arcgis

I am currently working on a project where I have to put in all the missing places on Google Maps, I'm currently using Google Map Maker to manually draw these buildings.

However, I already have the updated map with all the buildings in an arcGIS map. I would like to know if there is any way I can write a script, or any API's or any other way of exporting the arcGIS map and importing it into Google Maps. Or any way to get the information off the arcGIS map and into Google Maps. I am currently researching how to go about doing this, but have not found any information that has been helpful.

Does anyone know if its even possible or any other suggestions besides manually drawing in these buildings?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have ArcGIS/ArcMap (you say you have an ArcGIS map), you can use ArcMap to export your buildings layer (shapefiles or feature class) from ArcGIS to KML files (Keyhole Markup Language).  Then you should be able to use those KML building layer files in Google Maps.  In ArcGIS/AcrMap 10.3 you will find this feature under ArcToolBox/Conversion Tools/To KML/Layer to KML and Map to KML.